# mutate (calculate) variables from one column based on specific row conditions in another col

Tags: r, dplyr, mutate

Here is the example dataframe:

```
data.frame(sample = c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'),
                 measure = c(20,30,40,60,60,20,60,50,40,10),
                 time = c(1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,7),
                 start = c(1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3),
                 end = c(4,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6))
```

```
   sample measure time start end
1       A      20    1     1   4
2       A      30    2     1   4
3       A      40    3     1   4
4       A      60    4     1   4
5       A      60    5     1   4
6       B      20    3     3   6
7       B      60    4     3   6
8       B      50    5     3   6
9       B      40    6     3   6
10      B      10    7     3   6
```

What I want to do is create a new column called "calc" that calculates the measure for time=end / time=start

I'm guessing group_by sample first but I'm having trouble figuring out how to reference the start and end times. Here's what the final data should look like

```
   sample measure time start end calc
1       A      20    1     1   4    3
2       A      30    2     1   4    3
3       A      40    3     1   4    3
4       A      60    4     1   4    3
5       A      60    5     1   4    3
6       B      20    3     3   6    2
7       B      60    4     3   6    2
8       B      50    5     3   6    2
9       B      40    6     3   6    2
10      B      10    7     3   6    2
```

Comment: I don't get it. Why is `calc` = 3 for `sample` A and not equal to 4?

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing. calc for SampleA is measure at time=4 (60) divided by measure at time=1 (20), which equals 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about (`d` being your dataframe):

```
library(dplyr)

d |>
  arrange(sample, time) |>
  rowwise() |>
  mutate(is_endpoint = any(time == start, time == end)) |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(calc = tail(measure[is_endpoint], 1) /
           head(measure[is_endpoint], 1),
         .by = sample
         ) |>
  select(-is_endpoint)
```

output:

```
 # A tibble: 10 x 6
   sample measure  time start   end  calc
   <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A           20     1     1     4     3
 2 A           30     2     1     4     3
 3 A           40     3     1     4     3
 4 A           60     4     1     4     3
 5 A           60     5     1     4     3
 6 B           20     3     3     6     2
 7 B           60     4     3     6     2
 8 B           50     5     3     6     2
 9 B           40     6     3     6     2
10 B           10     7     3     6     2
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great assuming end measure is > start measure, which was all I had in the original data. But if I set sample B end measure  at t = 6 to be equal to 10, instead of 0.5 (10/20) I would get 2 because it's taking max/min.

Comment: Oops. See edited version, please. To make sure, data are now first sorted by group and time, so that `head` and `tail` indeed return the relevant endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have made an error in your expected results.  Sample A rows seem to be a difference while sample B seems to be a ratio.  If you wanted the latter, shouldn't calc be 4 for all the A samples.

If we start with your data frame as df:

```
df<-data.frame(sample = c('A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B'),
                 measure = c(20,30,40,60,60,20,60,50,40,10),
                 time = c(1,2,3,4,5,3,4,5,6,7),
                 start = c(1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3),
                 end = c(4,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,6))
```

The data.table package lets you do either calculation in one line

```
 library(data.table)
 DT<-data.table(df)
    
 DT[,calc_ratio:=end/start]
 DT[,calc_difference:=end-start]
 DT
```

to give:

```
    sample measure time start end calc_ratio calc_difference
 1:      A      20    1     1   4          4               3
 2:      A      30    2     1   4          4               3
 3:      A      40    3     1   4          4               3
 4:      A      60    4     1   4          4               3
 5:      A      60    5     1   4          4               3
 6:      B      20    3     3   6          2               3
 7:      B      60    4     3   6          2               3
 8:      B      50    5     3   6          2               3
 9:      B      40    6     3   6          2               3
10:      B      10    7     3   6          2               3
```

Comment: So the calc column is calculated from the measure column and not the time. The time just indicates which start and end measure columns to take